# VueJs Disable/Enable Div when selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I make it in vue.js, if Option A is selected div b disable, and when Option B is selected div A is disable using Vue.js.

```
<div id="app">

    <select>

        <option>A</option>

        <option>B</option>

    </select>

    <div id="a">

            A

    </div>

    <div id="b">

            B

    </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to disable a div. The disabled attribute is only relevant for input-like elements. See the full list: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should search [Vue's Methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

**Updated: 19/06/2017 - 16:35**

And if you want to code sample you can use this to example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        selected: ''
    },
})
```

```css
#a {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background-color: gray;
}

#b {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <select v-model="selected">
        <option disabled value="">Select div name</option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
    <div id="a" v-if="selected === 'a'">
      Div A
    </div>
    <div id="b" v-else>
      Div B
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not utilizing vue very much.

Comment: @BertEvans Yes you're right. I changed my code. He can use v-if and v-else. **I think**, Vue not just a template. So, if we need some JS code, we can use even if it is very simple.

Comment: @MathewMagante if this codes ok, you can mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

If by disabling you mean to hide id or remove it from DOM - yes, you  can do it with Vue.

Applies to both:
1. Assign the select to the model like `v-model='selected'`
2. Initiate it in the model: `data() { return { selected: null; (...) } }`

**v-if - DIV will be removed/insterted from/into DOM**

1. On your divs: `<div id='a' v-if="selected=== 'a'"`

**v-show - div will be hidden/shown**

1. On your divs: `<div id='a' v-show="selected=== 'a'"`

Comment: SO is not free coding service. You should try to do that by yourself. It is really simple job. You will learn much more doing it by yourself. I gave you solution for your question. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html

Comment: @MathewMagante Read the Vuejs guide and you will understand after awhile. It's better to write the code yourself than spoonfed. It's for your own good too!